# Drawing working in onDrawForeground but not in onDraw

Tags: android, view, ondraw, android-constraintlayout, custom-view

I was working on Developing a Custom View class (DatePicker) by extending ConstraintsLayout along with following children:

- 3 RecyclerViews
- 2 Buttons

I wanted to draw a rectangle over the view so that it show the picked date in DatePicker. I wrote the following code in onDraw method:

```
LinearLayout parentContainer = findViewById(R.id.id_container_lists);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorSelectedDate, getContext().getTheme()));
    } else {
        paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorSelectedDate));
    }

    paint.setAlpha(100);
    Rect rect = new Rect(0, (parentContainer.getBottom() - parentContainer.getTop())/2 - 40, parentContainer.getRight(), (parentContainer.getBottom() - parentContainer.getTop())/2 + 100);
    canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
```

but nothing was displaying over the view. I tried debugging and the code inside onDraw was executing but after execution there was nothing drawn on my custom view.

Then I tried overriding onDrawForeground method and copied the exact same code in this method and it worked.
My app is now working, but I just wanted to know why it didn't work in onDraw function? What I could have done to make it work in onDraw method?

Answer (score 0):

`onDraw` is called before `drawChild` which means that all children are drawn after the rectangle, which in this case is you background.

But it seems a bit overly complex to do it like this, why not just put a view inside the ConstrantsLayout that draws the square?

Comment: I tried by writing super.onDraw on both top and botton. Didn't worked.
I tried both with and without setWillNotDraw. Didn't worked.
And I had to implement a custom view that's why using this strategy.